# What does “loi Évin oblige” mean?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

> En 2016, Jennifer Le Néchet remporte le Diageo World Class, un des
>   plus prestigieux concours dans le monde du bar. Peu médiatisé en
>   France – **loi Evin oblige** –, ce « Top Chef » version cocktail trouve
>   cette année-là un écho inhabituel dans la presse française, fière de
>   célébrer cette première **victoire hexagonale.**

I don't understand these two expressions (highlighted in bold) I found in a news article. What do they mean?

Link to the article for context: https://www.lemonde.fr/m-gastronomie/article/2018/09/13/les-femmes-secouent-le-shaker_5354255_4497540.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one, **loi Évin oblige** means "à cause de la loi Évin" ou "grâce à la loi Évin ", depending on whether you see the effect as negative (the former) or positive (the latter). This is equivalent to "because of" or "thanks to".

Here, it is seen as negative because the loi Évin [restricts the advertisement of alcohol and tobacco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loi_%C3%89vin). (thanks to @Luke Sawczak for the information)

Secondly, **victoire hexagonale** means a victory by a French entrant. This is because [France is commonly referred to as "l'hexagone"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagone_(France)) due to its shape. And "hexagonale" means hexagon-shaped, so in this case it means "a victory for France".

Comment: Nice answer. You could add that the loi Évin is relevant to how little the cocktail was "mediatized" because it [restricts the advertisement of alcohol and tobacco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loi_%C3%89vin).